# Install kerberos client without interactive session

Tags: apt, docker

Hello I am configuring a docker image on top of Ubuntu. I have to install kerberos client. This is simple

```
apt-get update -qq
apt-get -y install krb5-user
```

The point is that the command does not terminate if I don't answer to the interactive prompt:

```
Default Kerberos version 5 realm:
```

Until I don't write something and press enter it doesn't quit. How to avoid it? I don't care to specify a default realm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` before it, then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments due to my low reputation. If the solution from the user ellayunyun doesn't work for you either and you're getting desperate, check `env` of the user you're actually getting the prompt with.

I tried to do the following:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo apt -y -qq install krb5-user
```

This resulted in root not having the env variable set. To fix this use the `-E` switch of sudo:

```
-E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
             existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error
             if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

Now the following worked for me:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt -y -qq install krb5-user
```